# extract all urls from a string

Tags: asp.net, url

I have a string of text that contains html, and I need to extract each url (most likely in img or a tags) to create a generic list of string objects.  I only want the urls from inside html tags, not in the text.  Is there an easy way to do this or will I have to resort to regular expressions?

If I have to resort to regular expressions, would you mind helping me out with that as well? :)

**UPDATE:**
To answer Seph, the input will be standard html.

```
<p>This is some html text.  my favourite website is <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a> and my favourite help site is <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a> and i check my email at <a href="http://www.gmail.com">gmail</a>.  the url to my site is http://www.example.com.   <img src="http://www.example.com/someimage.jpg" alt=""/></p>
```

And I want

- http://www.google.com
- http://www.stackoverflow.com
- http://www.gmail.com
- http://www.example.com/someimage.jpg

the end result should be All urls in any html tag, ignoring those are are "plain text"

**UPPERDATE**
Although he deleted his answer, I want to thank Jerry Bullard for bringing to my attention
Regex Buddy (http://www.regexbuddy).  I wanted to upvote your answer but its gone.  Bring it back and you get a vote!

Comment: Some text would be helpful, along with the exact desired output.

Comment: @codemonkey12: see my update based on your RegexBuddy comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should help:

```
    private List<string> GetUrlStrings(string text)
    {
        List<string> listURL = new List<string>();
        Regex regex = new Regex("href\\s*=\\s*(?:(?:\\\"(?<url>[^\\\"]*)\\\")|(?<url>[^\\s]* ))");
        MatchCollection mathColl = regex.Matches(text);

        foreach (Match match in mathColl)
        {
            foreach (Group group in match.Groups)
            {
                if (!group.Value.StartsWith("href")) // workaround regex issue
                {
                    listURL.Add(group.Value);
                }
            }
        }
        return listURL;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 approaches using LINQ to XML and regex. Although some people frown upon parsing HTML with regex, this particular case doesn't have nested elements so it is a reasonable solution. LINQ to XML would only work if your HTML is well-formed. Otherwise take a look at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).

**EDIT:** for your sample `Elements()` works with LINQ to XML. However, if you have many nested HTML tags then you may want to use `Descendants()` to reach all desired tags.

```
string input = @"<p>This is some html text.  my favourite website is <a href=""http://www.google.com"">google</a> and my favourite help site is <a href=""http://www.stackoverflow.com"">stackoverflow</a> and i check my email at <a href=""http://www.gmail.com"">gmail</a>.  the url to my site is http://www.mysite.com.   <img src=""http://www.someserver.com/someimage.jpg"" alt=""""/></p>";
var xml = XElement.Parse(input);
var result = xml.Elements()
                .Where(e => e.Name == "img" || e.Name == "a")
                .Select(e => e.Name == "img" ?
                            e.Attribute("src").Value : e.Attribute("href").Value);
foreach (string item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

string pattern = @"<(?:a|img).+?(?:href|src)=""(?<Url>.+?)"".*?>";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["Url"].Value);
}
```

**EDIT #2:** in response to your update about RegexBuddy, I wanted to point out the tool I use. [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) is a good free tool (email registration only, but it's free). The author also wrote [The 30 Minute Regex Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx) which you can use to follow along and is included in the help file of Expresso.

Answer (score -1):

This code might be of some help :) Taken from http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class LinkGetter {
    private Pattern htmltag;
    private Pattern link;
    private final String root;

    public LinkGetter(String root) {
        this.root = root;
        htmltag = Pattern.compile("<a\\b[^>]*href=\"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>");
        link = Pattern.compile("href=\"[^>]*\">");
    }

    public List<String> getLinks(String url) {
        List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(new URL(url).openStream()));
            String s;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((s = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(s);
            }

            Matcher tagmatch = htmltag.matcher(builder.toString());
            while (tagmatch.find()) {
                Matcher matcher = link.matcher(tagmatch.group());
                matcher.find();
                String link = matcher.group().replaceFirst("href=\"", "")
                        .replaceFirst("\">", "");
                if (valid(link)) {
                    links.add(makeAbsolute(url, link));
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return links;
    }

    private boolean valid(String s) {
        if (s.matches("javascript:.*|mailto:.*")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private String makeAbsolute(String url, String link) {
        if (link.matches("http://.*")) {
            return link;
        }
        if (link.matches("/.*") && url.matches(".*$[^/]")) {
            return url + "/" + link;
        }
        if (link.matches("[^/].*") && url.matches(".*[^/]")) {
            return url + "/" + link;
        }
        if (link.matches("/.*") && url.matches(".*[/]")) {
            return url + link;
        }
        if (link.matches("/.*") && url.matches(".*[^/]")) {
            return url + link;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot make the link absolute. Url: " + url
                + " Link " + link);
    }
}
```